# splitting an array into subarrays by variables value

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of ages.

I want to split the array in to 4 subarrays by the age value.

A -> 0...25

B -> 26...50

c -> 51...75

d -> 76 +

I have no problem iterating through the array and append to different arrays by the age value.

```
            let subArrays: [[Int]] = [[], [], [], []]
            for age in ages {
                switch age {
                case 0...25:
                    subArrays[0].append(age)
                case 26...50:
                    subArrays[1].append(age)
                case 51...75:
                    subArrays[2].append(age)
                default:
                    subArrays[3].append(age)
                }
            }
```

My questions is:
Is there a cleaner way to do this using `map`, `split` or any other function.

Thanks

Comment: Is it safe to assume you meant `d -> 76+` instead of `d -> 85+`?

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't use `map` or anything fancy but you can easily eliminate the `switch`:

```
var subArrays: [[Int]] = [[], [], [], []]
for age in ages {
    subArrays[min((age - 1) / 25, 3)].append(age)
}
```

The use of `min` ensures all values of 76 and greater go into the last slot.

And to test, with all boundary cases, try:

```
let ages = [ 50, 67, 75, 76, 25, 12, 26, 51, 99, 45, 0, 120, 16 ]
```

And then:

```
print(subArrays)
```

Gives:

> [[25, 12, 0, 16], [50, 26, 45], [67, 75, 51], [76, 99, 120]]

Comment: * no floats or negative numbers I assume.

Comment: @l'L'l The OP's code shows the results being an array of `Int` so I assume the array of ages are also `Int`. And nobody has a negative age. But my answer actually puts values from -23 to -1 in the first result array.

Comment: True, although depending on how you look at it some scientists might argue someone (not living) could be 11,000 years old too... but maybe that's way off for this question :)

Answer (score 2):

A more generic version that does not depend on any mathematical property of your ranges:

```
func split<T>(array: [T], ranges: [CountableClosedRange<T>]) -> [[T]] {
    var result = Array(repeating: [T](), count: ranges.count)

    for element in array {
        if let subIndex = ranges.index(where: { $0 ~= element }) {
            result[subIndex].append(element)
        }
    }
    return result
}

let ages = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
let subarrays = split(array: ages, ranges: [0...25, 26...50, 51...75, 76...Int.max])
```

Note that it does not check for overlapping ranges.

Comment: You would need to pass in better ranges to handle floating point ages if that were desired. The sample ranges would't catch 25.5, for example, if an array of `Float` ages were used. I only mention this since the goal of your answer is to handle other types.

Answer (score 0):

Based on rmaddy's answer (practically the same) but within one line:

```
let subs = (0...3).map { sub in ages.filter { sub == min(($0 - 1) / 25, 3) } }
```

Comment: This is kind of slick but it is hard to read and understand and it ends up iterating the ages array 4 times instead of just once.